# Which version of FFMPEG supports HLS v4

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

Wanted to know which version of FFMPEG library supports Http Live Streaming (HLS) V4.

Specification for this protocol is at:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-08

Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFmpeg does not yet support HLS version 4.

As of 2013-07-29 (commit [c44191039944526dd7eb6e536990b555837961f5](http://git.libav.org/?p=libav.git;a=blobdiff;f=libavformat/hls.c;h=0c836c75363a90ad469e6e585a479f3bebd2fe8a;hp=5eb98c51a8feccf0ffea5d935d4731199c654e31;hb=c44191039944526dd7eb6e536990b555837961f5;hpb=e1d5b244761cf69db655ad7ece1dbf2c13dd4fce)), libav/ffmpeg have supported version 3 of the protocol. There's not yet a numbered release including this patch.

Comment: Thanks. Then, which version of HLS spec. is supported by latest FFMPEG?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version (v4.3.3) of FFMpeg supports [HLS version 7](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8216), check out `hls_segment_type` option in [the documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#toc-Options-8).

> hls_segment_type flags
>
> - Possible values:
>
>   - ‘mpegts’
>
>     - Output segment files in MPEG-2 Transport Stream format. This is compatible with all HLS versions.
>   - ‘fmp4’
>
>     - Output segment files in fragmented MP4 format, similar to MPEG-DASH. fmp4 files may be used in **HLS version 7** and above.

You can also try generating HLS files then read `EXT-X-VERSION` in the generated plyalist (.m3u8) , which should be `7`, means the protocol version.